# Why use ItemSource="{Binding}" Without A Path

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I was reading some code and came across this;

```
<TabControl ItemSource="{Binding}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}" />
```

I have a pretty good handle on {Binding Path=Something} but I can't find a sastisfactory nswer to ItemSource="{Binding}" all by itself. The nearest I got to an answer was

"This simply returns the current data context (more about that later)." BTW, there was nothing more.

So I wonder if anyone would like to expand on this and leave out all the "One Way, Two Way, Element... binding. Just the part about {Binding}.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a path in a binding, it's relative to the `DataContext`; if the path is empty, then it refers to the `DataContext` itself. So the binding will just return the current `DataContext` as its value.

Comment: Would that not be the default if it was just left out?

Comment: @ScottinTexas, if what was left out?

Comment: Sorry, typed while just thinking. If the {Binding} was left out, wouldn't the ItemsSource inherit the DataContext of the parent?

Comment: @ScottinTexas, the TabControl would still inherit the DataContext, but the ItemsSource would be null. It wouldn't make sense for all properties to get the value of the DataContext...

Answer (score 0):

ItemsSource="{Binding}" means binding the datacontext of the TabControl to the ItemsSource.

ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Something}", means binding the (DataContext of the TabControl).Something to the ItemsSource.